# Getting an undefined variable error for variable defined within function in php

Tags: php, undefined-variable

I have the following code:

```
$SpeedA = 5; 
$SpeedB = 5; 
$Distance = 20; 

function CalDistance ($SpeedA, $SpeedB, 
$Distance)
{
    $DistanceA = (($SpeedA / $SpeedB) * 
    $Distance) / (1 + ($SpeedA / $SpeedB));

    Return $DistanceA;

}
echo $DistanceA;
```

I get this error:

> Notice: undefined variable $DistanceA

Why `$DistanceA` is regarded as undefined and how to fix it?

Comment: Side note: I'd of ordinarily have closed this as an existing undefined index/variable duplicate, but I applaud your use of the "undefined-variable" tag. You can consult the answer that was given below; it seems to be correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call the function `CalDistance`, before your `echo`. So, you try to `echo` an undefined `$DistanceA`.

So, you could do something like this:

```
$SpeedA = 5; 
$SpeedB = 5; 
$Distance = 20; 

function CalDistance ($SpeedA, $SpeedB, 
$Distance)
{
    $DistanceA = (($SpeedA / $SpeedB) * 
    $Distance) / (1 + ($SpeedA / $SpeedB));

    Return $DistanceA;

}

$call = CalDistance($SpeedA, $SpeedB, $Distance);
echo $call;
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I'm new and some times I just look at it too long and can see the wood for the trees. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. If it solved your problem, then please accept the answer. So, that future readers, see that your problem was solved.